# My script can't send the emails properly with postfix installed

Tags: php, email

Hello i made this script:

index.php:

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"><tr><td><strong>Whitelist Request </strong></td></tr></table><table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"><tr><td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_whitelist.php"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3"><tr><td width="16%">Username</td><td width="2%">:</td><td width="82%"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="50"></td></tr><tr><td>Paysafe</td><td>:</td><td><input name="paysafe" type="text" id="paysafe" size="50"></td></td><tr></tr><td>Name</td><td>:</td><td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td></tr><tr><td>Email</td><td>:</td><td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td></tr></table></form></td></tr></table>
```

Email Sender:

```
<?php

// Contact subject
$subject ="Minecraft Server Whitelist Request"; 

// Details
$message="Name: $name \n Username: $username \n Paysafe: $paysafe  ";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='n************@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "I have received your whitelist request. Please wait.";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

The contents of the textboxes doesen't appear in the mail.
Any ideas?

Comment: please reformat your question. remove useless tags

Comment: Looks like your script relied on `register_globals`, instead of accessing the `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send emails with `php`. Here's and example to send an email via gmail using an html file as body and attaching an image:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

---

**TIPS:**

1 - Check other PHPMailer [examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).
2 - PHPMailer [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).
3 - Set `SMTPDebug = 2` or higher, to see what the remote SMTP server says.
4 - You may have to enable [less secure apps](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) on you gmail account.

Comment: Care to comment the downvote ?